# Radiative Cooling of metal object

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation

We have this experiment where a metal bar is heated and then we have to make a model for the cooling that occurs. We get numbers for how long it takes the metal bar to cool from 200 to 100 degrees Celsius, and we have to calculate how long it takes for the object to cool to 50 degrees. Now, I want to calculate what the cooling would be like if it was only radiative. I know that $T(t)=T_0+(T_s−T_0)e^{−kt}$ is the formula for cooling by convection, so I'm wondering what the equivalent of that is for radiative cooling. In other words, what is the formula for radiative cooling?

Comment: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/thermo/cootime.html

Comment: I need to take the air into account. The website was good, but they don't take that into account.

Comment: They do. They call it $T_{ambient}$.

Comment: You said that you wanted to calculate $T(t)$ in the situation in which the cooling is only radiative...anyway, just sum the two contributions: $\frac{dE}{dt} = - (a (T-T_e)^4 + b (T-T_e))$, where $T_e$ is the temperature of the environment and $a,b$ are constant coefficients.

Comment: Even if the cooling is only radiative, dosen't the temperature of the air still make a difference?

Comment: Yes, the air makes a difference: $Φ= εσA(T_{metal}^4-T_{air}^4)$. It becomes hard to integrate,

Comment: Yeah, I tried integrating below, but the equation i got seemed to complicated, I'm not even sure if it's correct. Should I just do as they do in that website and disregard the ambient temperature?

Comment: As a *tentative* starting point, yes. Judge the error you're making by comparing numerically $T^4-T_a^4$ and $T^4$.

Comment: @valerio92: $a (T-T_e)^4$ is incorrect.

Comment: @Gert You're right, it should be $(T^4-T_e^4)$.

Comment: @valerio92: no, not at all. Look at my answer to his first question.    http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/255670/cooling-of-a-hot-metal-object-in-air/255675#255675 With the right loss function, that's quite a handful to integrate. The main integral looks like this: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=DSolve%5By%27(T)%3D%3D1%2F(T%5E4-a%5E4)%5D

Comment: @Gert Of course, I looked at it better and realized (Sorry, I deleted the previous comment by accident)

Answer (score 1):

If you assume that the object radiates as a blackbody, then the Stefan-Boltzmann Law tells you that the power radiated by the object will be

$P = A \sigma T^4$

where $A$ is the surface area, $\sigma$ is the Stefan-Boltzmann constant, and $T$ is the temperature.  If your object is not a blackbody, you can parameterize the above equation with an additional constant, $\epsilon$, called the emissivity.

From this you should be able to figure out the temperature as a function of time by knowing that the thermal energy is proportional to temperature and that the power is equal to the time derivative of energy.

Comment: That loss function is for radiative losses in *vacuum*. In air some gets radiated back.

Comment: That's true, although I would imagine that that would only result in a change of the effective emissivity of the object.  It would be unlikely to change the temperature dependence of the power by much.

Comment: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/thermo/cootime.html If OP wants a proper solution then it has to be done properly.

Comment: I understand that, but the ambient temperature does not enter into the temperature dependence of the cooling time, unless you are assuming that the ambient temperature is changing due to the heat loss from the object.  But that's going to be a second-order effect and I've neglected it in my answer.

Comment: It changes the DV for the problem *quite drastically*. For very hot objects you could neglect ambient $T$ but then it becomes an approximation. It depends what one wants to achieve, of course.

Answer (score 0):

[The answer lies in your previous question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/255670/cooling-of-a-hot-metal-object-in-air/255675#255675).

Use the heat loss function for radiative cooling and plug it into the differential equation I set up for you in the answer. Then integrate.

Comment: Yes, that's what I did at first, but I ran into some trouble into integrating. What I got was $$\Large{tεσA4(T_{air}^4)/mc_v=ln\frac{T_{metal,t}+T_{air}}{-T_{metal,t}+T_{air}}-ln\frac{T_{metal,0}+T_air}{-T_{metal,0},+T_air}+2arctan\frac{T_{metal,t}}{T_{air}}-2arctan\frac{T_{metal,0}}{T_{air}}}$$

which does not seem correct. Maybe it is, but I doubt it, that's why I came back here.

Comment: That's difficult to judge w/o the derivation.

Comment: What I did was basically just switch $$Φ=hA(T_{metal}-T_{air})$$ with  $$Φ= εσA(T_{metal}^4-T_{air}^4)$$ from the previous question and then integrate. This is what I got.

Comment: Like I said: difficult to judge w/o seeing *how* you did it. I'm not a mind reader and that integral is not easy. Why not put the derivation in your question?

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=DSolve%5By%27(T)%3D%3D1%2F(T%5E4-a%5E4)%5D  gives the main *form* of the difficult integral.

Comment: Yes, I was about to write that, I used wolframalpha to get that equation, then inputted my limits on the integral.